# How to build Forth for embedded devices

Tags: microcontroller, pic, embedded

So far I have just found this paper which provide a guide to achieve that:
*[MOVING FORTH. Part 1: Design Decisions in the Forth Kernel](http://www.bradrodriguez.com/papers/moving1.htm)*

1. Is there a more recent guide?
2. Which Forth is better for that purpose?

I am planning to use it with PIC16F877A, and I know that [PicForth](https://rfc1149.net/devel/picforth.html) exists, but it is just a compiler, not a system to communicate with a terminal window by a serial connection (that's why I am going to use Forth).

Comment: Looks like a PIC16 is not going be suitable for pForth; I updated my answer to recommend a PIC32 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Mecrisp Forth](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mecrisp/files/). I've been using it on STM32 microcontrollers.

It compiles to about 25K and is probably a lot of work (assembly language) to get it working on a PIC32. But if you do, you'll have a fast small Forth implementation. If you do, let me know.

It is worth a look as it is as cutting edge a Forth implementation as I've seen.

Comment: Even the smallest STM32 parts are orders of magnitude larger than the PIC16 that the author wanted to target.

Comment: Don't post personal information in answers

Comment: I have found the same and used stm32f103 as they are the same price, but I used custom Indirect threading version and used code from mecrisp"compile to RAM and FLASH", jones forth"model" and hforth"multitasking".
I used indirect threading to be easily ported and I think forth with optimization isn't a good idea"injecting assembly code is the nice solution from cross compilation". BTW mecrisp forth is very good see this doc http://hightechdoc.net/mecrisp-stellaris/_build/html/f0-disco-blinkies.html

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out [pForth](http://www.softsynth.com/pforth/), which is a portable implementation in C.  The PIC16F877A has 14K of Flash, and only 368 bytes of RAM so there is no way pForth is going to fit.  The PIC16F877A also has a 16-deep hardware stack used only for return addresses, and no parameter stack.  These restrictions would have probably ruled out using a PIC16 for pForth anyway, even if you could get one with enough Flash and RAM.

Based on gbarry's answer, it looks like you're going to need a *much* bigger microcontroller for pForth.  You might as well skip the PIC18 (which has a maximum program size of 128K), and also the PIC24 (which also has a max of 128K) and go with a PIC32.  The [PIC32MX170F256B](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001168H.pdf) has 256K of Flash and 64K of RAM, and [costs under $4](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/PIC32MX170F256B-I%2FSP/PIC32MX170F256B-I%2FSP-ND/4902616).  It comes in a 28-pin DIP instead of a 40-pin one though.

You also might want to check out the following books:

[Programming A Problem Oriented Language: Forth - how the internals work](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K3PIYX2) by Charles H. Moore (the original creator of Forth)

This book is only available as a Kindle book, but you can get a free reader for the PC and most portable devices like the iPhone, iPad and Android equivalents.

[Forth Application Techniques: Course Notebook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1419685767), 5th Edition by Elizabeth D. Rather (who was a co-founder of Forth, Inc.)

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded pForth on @tcrosley's advice, compiled under OS X, and the standalone image is 180 K.  This is one of several stumbling points that has kept me from realizing a goal similar to the asker's.  Only I've been trying for 15 years :)  Most are too large, some lack an interpreter, some are not in C, some wouldn't build, some expected a Windows environment, and so on.

The information provided by Brad Rodriguez is still applicable to building a number of FORTH systems.  I'm not aware of any updates, and since it's his site, that's where any updates would be.  I recently was referring to these papers and I am still attempting to create my own small FORTH written in C.  I've had a little success, but I can tell you, there's a lot in the details.  This is not the sort of thing you can do while simultaneously trying to make progress on an embedded project.

Note that FORTH originally expected to have a block of RAM where new dictionary words get compiled.  You either have to deal with not much RAM, or come up with a way of writing to the program flash.

I have also tried something called FlashForth (this one's written in assembler) and it did work, but I put it on a fairly large PIC18F6620.  I got distracted trying to figure out the dictionary internals and where stuff was stored, so I never got to where I could do development with it.  I suggest trying it if you can get your hands on something in the PIC18F family...even just to try it.  On that note, there are some 18F parts that are pin compatible with their 16F counterparts, so if cost is a concern, just use the bigger parts for development if FORTH isn't actually going into the final product.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info re the size of pForth.  I've modified my recommendations from a PIC16F to a PIC32MX.  Still under $4, and available in a DIP package   I also realized the PIC16 probably would not be a good fit for Forth, since it has a limited 16-deep hardware return stack, and no parameter stack.